# Requirements are satisified, but unable to import libraries in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-import

I want to import numpy and pandas in jupyter but I get the message:

```
----> 1 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Now when I open the anaconda prompt and do `pip list` then I can see the latest version of numpy

Even when I say `pip install` it says requirement already satisfied.

I know that this relates in some way to the PATH of python.

Honestly as someone from a math background learning how to code I'm really unsure what this means and how I can check and fix whether the Path is correct or not.

Does it just mean where jupyter looks for `python.exe`? I dont know for sure where to check for this.

`where python` in the Anaconda Prompt gives me:

```
C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
```

When I run this on the jupyter notebook:

```
from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_data_dir
print(jupyter_data_dir())
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\NyName\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
```

Is this the source of the problem?

Comment: You could just open a jupyter terminal and install the package though there and that should fix it. Also make sure your pip install the python version of the package as your jupyter python env.

Comment: so I tried that too, using `!pip install numpy` within jupyter but that didn't fix it either. I just got `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\myname\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.17.2)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your Jupyter kernel is using a different Python from the one in your Anaconda prompt.

If you don't use virtual environments, you should start. To make one, open an Anaconda prompt and do this (changing the name `myenv` to whatever you like):

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7 jupyter matplotlib pandas
```

Change the version of Python or the other packages too if you want.

When that's finished, switch to that environment:

```
conda activate myenv
```

Now do this:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv
```

This adds a Jupyter kernel for this environment. **You only need to do this once, after creating the environment.**

Now restart Jupyter notebook or Jupyter lab or whatever. Or install more stuff in this environment if you want. You can just use `pip` like so:

```
pip install awesomepackage
```

You should now see your environment under **Kernel** > **Change kernel**, and under **New** when making a new notebook.

Forgive me if you know all this, but this is the only way I've been able to keep environments straight, and to know *exactly* where I'm installing stuff. Good luck!

Comment: No, I'm new to this and I didn't know this, thank you. So the matplotlib and pandas at the end specify which packages are included in that environment? So should I add other packages like numpy when I want to use them too? What if I need many more packages, do they all need to be specified in that first line?

Comment: You can specify them when creating the environment, or you can add them later with `conda` or `pip` (or in other ways, but you'll mostly use those two at first). You don't have to specify any packages when you do the `conda create`, but usually you at least want `jupyter` and `matplotlib` (which requires `numpy` so you get that 'for free'). You don't have to specify the Python version either, but I think it's a good habit.

Comment: So will I need to activate the environment every time I want to code on it? This actually helped a lot because I'm supposed to be using python 3.6 and not 3.7

Comment: Yes, but if you're in Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter Lab, the `ipykernel` thing (which you only need to do once per environment, right after creating it) means you can just choose the environment from within Jupyter. (So no need to go into a terminal and type `conda activate myenv`.)

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I've found is that simply using `pip install` is incorrect.

[This link](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/) here shows the way it has to be done. By using the command:
`!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy`

I am correctly able to import the package and use it.

If anyone could help me understand how this command works that'd be super helpful. This has solved my problem but I don't really know why or how.

Comment: Clever, but you should not have to run `pip` this way. I hope my answer helps.

Comment: could you help me understand why I shouldn't?

Comment: I mean, you *can*, but it seems unnecessarily clunky. Basically, if you can't just type `pip install pkgname`, there's something wrong with your paths and/or environments.

Comment: right, there is indeed an issue with path and environment. Would you be able to tell me how I can diagnose such problems, or direct me towards some material regarding this? I don't know what to google honestly.

Comment: Once you start using environments for everything, you basically won't need to worry about paths etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to Install MNE-Python into my local Python environment. I had the above issue **Requirements are satisfied, but unable to import libraries in jupyter notebook** as it shows *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mne'*.

I figured my localhost is running Python version 3.11.7 and Anaconda is running 3.11.5, to resolve the issue I upgraded Anaconda environment Python using the below code

```
conda install python=3.11.7
```

Now the issue is resolved